# Symfony multilingual forms

Tags: forms, symfony, multilingual

I have a preexisting multilingual form made with php without Symfony which looks like this:
[image: Selection of language]

When English is selected, it looks like this:
[image: English form]
When German is selected, it looks like this:
[image: German form]

In a php file, the text is in german but with the option to be changed into other languages if it has been selected so by the user, for example like this:

```
<?php echo(textFUp('Muttersprache', $lang)) ?>
...
<input type="text" tabindex="24" name="FUp_ses_mom_mtongue" size="12" value="<?php echo show($patient, 'E_FUp::FUp_ses_mom_mtongue'); ?>" />
...
```

It makes use of a function called textFUp, here is a piece of that function:

```
/****
 * DESCRIPTION
 *  This module contains a function to change the language of the form.
 *  All translations are saved in this module.
  ******
 */


function textFUp() {
    if (func_num_args() < 2 || func_num_args() > 3)
        exit;

    $text      = func_get_arg(0);
    $lang      = func_get_arg(1);
    $exception = (func_num_args() == 3) ? func_get_arg(2) : '';

    if ($text == 'deutsch') {
        if ($lang == 'f') {
            return 'francais';
        }
        elseif ($lang == 'i') {
            return 'italiano';
        }
        elseif ($lang == 'e') {
            return 'english';
        }
        else {
            return $text;
        }
    }
    elseif ($text == 'Liebe Eltern,') {
        if ($lang == 'f') {
            return 'Chers Parents,';
        }
        elseif ($lang == 'i') {
            return 'Caro Genitore,';
        }
        elseif ($lang == 'e') {
            return 'Dear Parents,';
        }
        else {
            return $text;
        }
    }
    elseif ($text == 'Wie geht es Ihrem Kind? Wie f&uuml;hlt es sich? Das m&ouml;chten wir gerne von Ihnen wissen.') {
        if ($lang == 'f') {
            return 'Vos r&eacute;ponses &agrave; ce questionnaire nous permettront de mieux conna&icirc;tre ce dont les enfants et les adolescents ont besoin pour se sentir heureux et en bonne sant&eacute;.';
        }
        elseif ($lang == 'i') {
            return 'Come sta suo/a figlio/a? Come si sente? Questo &egrave; quello che vorremmo sapere da lei.';
        }
        elseif ($lang == 'e') {
            return 'How is your child? How does she/he feel? This is what we would like to know from you.';
        }
        else {
            return $text;
        }
    }
    elseif ($text == 'Bitte &uuml;berlegen Sie, wie es Ihrem Kind in der letzten Woche gegangen ist. Beantworten Sie dann bitte die folgenden Fragen, so wie Sie es von Ihrem Kind und seinen Erfahrungen wissen oder vermuten.') {
        if ($lang == 'f') {
            return 'Si vous avez plusieurs enfants, nous vous demandons dans tout le questionnaire de r&eacute;pondre &agrave; propos de l&#39;enfant qui remplit le questionnaire-enfant. Lisez attentivement chaque question et cochez la case qui correspond le mieux &agrave; ce que vous pensez. Quand vous r&eacute;pondez, essayez de penser &agrave; la semaine pass&eacute;e.';
        }
        elseif ($lang == 'i') {
            return 'E&#39; pregato di rispondere alle seguenti domande nel migliore dei modi, assicurandosi che la risposta rifletta effettivamente la realt&agrave; di suo/a figlio/a. E&#39; pregato di fare riferimento alla esperienze vissute da suo figlio/a nell&#39;ultima settimana.';
        }
        elseif ($lang == 'e') {
            return 'Please answer the following questions to the best of your knowledge, ensuring that the answers you give reflect the perspective of your child. Please try to remember your child&#39;s experiences over the last week.';
        }
        else {
            return $text;
        }
    }

...

elseif ($text == 'Muttersprache') {
        if ($lang == 'f') {
            return 'Langue maternelle';
        }
        elseif ($lang == 'i') {
            return 'Lingua madre';
        }
        elseif ($lang == 'e') {
            return 'Mother tongue';
        }
        else {
            return $text;
        }
...
}
```

So my question is how to do this in Symfony in the easiest and quickest way, knowing I have already an old running version without Symfony?

**For example how to have different texts for radio buttons in a Form\DataType depending on the language selected?**

The monolingual version would be:

```
->add('variable', 'choice', array(
    'choices'=>array(
        't'=>0,
        'some monolingual text'=>1,
        'some other monolingual text'=>2,
        'more monolingual text'=>9),
    'choices_as_values'=>true,
    'expanded'=>true,
))
```

And in the form.html.twig: for example the monolingual radio buttons are called like this:

```
{{form_widget(form.variable)}}
```

Comment: please check http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html first

Comment: LBA, I have went trhough this link but I did not find a solution to my question. Where do you see the answer to my question in that link? thank you!

Comment: Just to understand: you actually have 2 forms (first for selecting language, second for all questions) or a 2 steps form, right?

Comment: A two steps form in a single php file. With a function defined separatelay in an other php file.

Comment: Read this document and install translator service, http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html

Comment: Thank you Archi, but I do not need a translation. All the texts are already translated. What I need is a way to display the form in the different versions without having to make a form for each specific language. Please have a look at the function textFUp(), where you can see the texts already translated. Thanks!

Comment: isn't it strange that you got the same link twice? please read and understand it. symfony translation is your friend here.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the links below and watching some youtube videos, I have come so far.
I installed and configured the translation component.
[Terminal command: composer require symfony/translation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/translation.html#translation-configuration)

In Symfony\app\config\config.yml: I uncommented "translator" and added parameters

```
# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en


framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
```

I am trying to figure out how to have several locale and switch between them easily. But this is another question. This should be solved following this explanation video in French: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FPupfu9jbUU (I am still not so far).

I created a folder and yaml files for each language:

```
Data\LiveBundle\Resources\translations\messages.es.yml
Data\LiveBundle\Resources\translations\messages.fr.yml
Data\LiveBundle\Resources\translations\messages.it.yml
```

etc.
They look something like this:

In messages.es.yml:

```
IntroFup:
      Greeting: Hello
...
```

In messages.fr.yml:

```
IntroFup:
      Greeting: Salut
...
```

And in form.html.twig:
    {{'Intro.Greeting'|trans}}

As for the radiobuttons, their translation has to be defined in the yaml files as well. I have not figured out another way. And in DataType, the names of the choices are let empty.

```
->add('variable', 'choice', array(
    'choices'=>array(
        ''=>0,
        ''=>1,
        ''=>2,
        ''=>9),
    'choices_as_values'=>true,
    'expanded'=>true,
))
```

Useful links:

```
[http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/components/translation/usage.html][2]
[An Introduction to Symfony's Translation Component][3]
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fcwUUGxlTIM][4]
[A well explained video in French but bad sound quality][5]
[Putting locale in url][6]
```